# Need Helping returning indices max sequence algorithm

Tags: algorithm, indices, divide-and-conquer, subsequence

I have the following algorithm which returns the sum of the greatest subsequence in an array.  The greatest sum is in either in the left half, right half, or in the middle of the array(divide and conquer)...  I can return the indices if it is through the middle. But if the subsequence is in the left or right half of the array, I can't figure out what they would be(recursion a bit confusing). I can define the indice's variables outside of the method if needed. Here is the method:

```
 private static int maxSumRec( int [ ] a, int left, int right )
{
    int maxLeftBorderSum = 0, maxRightBorderSum = 0;
    int leftBorderSum = 0, rightBorderSum = 0;
    int center = ( left + right ) / 2;

    if( left == right )  // Base case
        return a[ left ] > 0 ? a[ left ] : 0;

    int maxLeftSum  = maxSumRec( a, left, center );
    int maxRightSum = maxSumRec( a, center + 1, right );

    for( int i = center; i >= left; i-- )
    {
        leftBorderSum += a[ i ];
        if( leftBorderSum > maxLeftBorderSum )
            maxLeftBorderSum = leftBorderSum;
    }

    for( int i = center + 1; i <= right; i++ )
    {
        rightBorderSum += a[ i ];
        if( rightBorderSum > maxRightBorderSum )
            maxRightBorderSum = rightBorderSum;
    }

    return max3( maxLeftSum, maxRightSum,
                 maxLeftBorderSum + maxRightBorderSum );
}
```

Comment: I believe I found the solution, can anyway tell if the maxLeftSum and maxRightSum would return the sum of half the array and not the maximum sequence?